# Hover state flickers rapidly when mouse is on edge of element

Tags: html, css, hover

I've created an anchor tag to appear like a button. When I hover over the element, the person's name transitions into just an acronym of their first and last name. When my mouse is just on the edge of the element, the hover starts to rapidly flicker ruining the smoothness of the effect.

Here's a codepen demonstrating the issue I'm having:

http://codepen.io/kedarjoyner/pen/JRYRxa

HTML

```
<a target="_blank" href="#">A<span>aron</span> Y<span>onda</span></a>
```

CSS

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #231f20;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid #231f20;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}


a:hover span {
  display: none;
}

a:hover  {
 color: orange;
 transition: .2s;
 border-color: orange;
 transition: .2s;
 width: 50px;
}
```

Comment: It's because you have 2 hover states acting at the same time. Take out a:hover span, you don't need it

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! I tried that, but then I can't hide the letters to turn the logo into an acronym.

Comment: I've also tried adding and removing those span letters as pseudo classes, but that didn't improve the issue either.

Comment: @Kedmasterk please accept the answer posted below by clicking on the grey checkmark icon on the left.

Comment: @herrh Thank you! Do you happen to know why targeting the div works as opposed to the anchor tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the solution. Wrap the button with a div and target the hover on the div instead of the anchor.

```css
body {
  font-family: Helvetical, Arial, sans-serif;
}

.name-logo {
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.name-logo a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #231f20;
  font-weight: 600;
  border: 2px solid #231f20;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}

.name-logo:hover a {
  color: orange;
  border-color: orange;
}

.name-logo:hover a span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="name-logo">
  <a target="_blank" href="#">A<span>aron</span> Y<span>onda</span></a>
</div>
```